# How do I prevent AngularJS routing from encoding a url parameter with a ~ (tilde)

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, url-routing, state.go

Currently when I pass a param to `$state.go` that includes a `~` it duplicates when the url is being created.

Example:

I search for `~abc`. Then pass to `$state.go('.', {myParam: "~abc"})`. Then inside url I have `https://localhost/somePath?myParam=~~abc`

According to RFC3986 the '~' must be percent-encoded in HTML forms to "%7E". If I encode prior then I still have the same issue. So I assume the value must be handled inside of `$stateProvider` or by customizing `$urlmatcherfactoryprovider` inside of UI router.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix by passing a type of `any` to my state's url queryParam since it is not encoded by UrlMatcherFactory by updating the `/state?:param` to `/state?{param:any}` since this is expected behavior for `~` to `~~`. More details can be found here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3790

Answer (score 0):

With the new [httpParamSerializer](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/11238) in AngularJS you can do it by writing your own paramSerializer and setting $httpProvider.defaults.paramSerializer.

Comment: This error seems to actually be a bug inside of angular ui-router with the UrlMatcherFactory. Could you provide some more context to your response? I am using the $stateParams to make my $http request and the params values are being transformed prior to the request